# connect win10 desktop,alert password Expired

Tags: windows

username and password is correct， also connect failed：
[image]

Answer (score 0):

### it should change sec Strategy：

- win+r run :secpol.msc
- find local policy -> security option
- find Sharing and security model for local accounts
- select Classic Mode
  [image]